# How to affect particle size over time?

Tags: particles

I'd like to spawn particles that change size over time. It would be nice if I could have complete control over how big they are at each percentage of their lifetime, but that is not a necessary feature. (I'm rendering the particles as objects.)

Comment: you can find a method to increase or decrease their size here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67024UyCZ6A

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you! Please feel free to write that up as an answer so I can officially accept it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is the method to increase the particles size through time, as explained by BlenderShortTests in [one of his tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67024UyCZ6A):

- Select your emitter and go to *Properties* > *Particles*, click *New*.
- In *Properties* > *Particles* > *Render*, click *Object* and choose the object that will be emitted as particles and its size.
- Go to your 3D view and press *alt A* to launch a preview of your emission animation, then stop it somewhere in its course.
- In *Properties* > *Particles* > *Textures*, add *New* and give it a name.
- In *Properties* > *Textures* > *Type*, choose *Blend*.
- In *Properties* > *Textures* > *Colors*, enable *Color Ramp*.
- In *Properties* > *Textures* > *Mapping* > *Coordinat*e > choose *Strand/Particles*.
- In *Properties* > *Textures* > *Influences*, unclick *Time* and enable *Size*.
- In *Properties* > *Textures* > *Colors*, play with the Ramp controller to increase or decrease the size of your emitted object through time.

The video also explains how to make a fade out effect on the particles: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67024UyCZ6A