# (2.8) how should I use a particles texture to stop emitting?

Tags: particles

I read [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/114310/14306) about using a texture to affect the particules size; and it works fine.

I have also read that to stop my emitter emitting particles, 
I could do the same on the "density" parameter.
But I can't make it work.

1 - could particles have several textures ?
2 - how should I fix my texture to stop emitting ?

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: Particles will emit where the texture has white color (in your case) and not at where the texture is black. So to stop emitting the particles, make the "brightness and contrast"  value zero of the texture for density.

Comment: Ok, so I don't have to use the "mapping" parameters but the "brightness" and "contrast" parameters ? And set them to zero ?  Thanks.

Comment: You do not need mapping. But as far as I know in the blender 2.8, particle texture does not update in animation.