# Dissolve Texture

Tags: particles

I am trying to dissolve a texture. This should actually be a quite easy effect however I am not able to let the particles fade out individually and scale them at the same time.

In my example I am using a particle system and an explode modifier with the **life** attribute checked and a simple blend texture scaling the particles over time.

In this tutorial https://youtu.be/gD8qlNdEt6E?t=1390 a uv texture on the explode modifiert is being used but I can't get it to work when recreating it in Blender 2.8

How would one create a dissolve effect with scaling & fading of the particles of a plane with a texutre applied to it?

[image]

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/114310/442

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would always advise to [read the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/simulate/explode.html).

The section on UV map reveals the secret.  If set then the short, the *U value* will give the age of the particle ranging from 0 to 1.  The *V value* is fixed at 0.5

To make use of this a node setup which makes use of this is required:

**Simple Fade**

[image: Simple Fade Node Setup]

Please note that if you're using Eevee as your renderer then you need to enable alpha blending in the material settings, and ( as I found out after much befuddlement )  that you want to disable the *Show Backface* option.

For scaling please see the answer by @moonboots:

[How to affect particle size over time?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/114310/442)

To get this working with the explode modifier, enable the *Size* option.  Just remember to enable and flip the colour ramp in the texture settings.

**Textured Fade**

So you don't want just to explode objects of a single color, you want to blow up colored stuff too, no problem, just use multiple UV Maps.

One UV Map is used for particle info as above, the other is used to texture in the usual way.  The node setup uses multiple UV nodes:

[image: Textured Fade Node Setup]

*Et voila*, an explosion of fading colour.

Comment: In my case however I can't make use of moonboots answer since I don't emit an object with the particle system. I use an explode modifier to explode the particles of the plane with a texture on it. The problem I encounter when following @moonboots solution is that my texture gets repeated on every particle but I need the particles to display just a part of the texture (like in a puzzle).

Comment: Well I used it, and it seemed to work.  The emitter is the object you're exploding.

Comment: But it won't do your texture stuff, not sure about that one.  I'll give it some thought, however you did not mention it in your original question and therefore this answer should suffice.  You are welcome!

Comment: Appreciate your help, thanks. I reworded my question to be a bit more precise. And you're right it doesn't do it with a texture applied to it and that is the problem. Tried many different approaches but can't get it to work. It's driving me nuts! I can't believe something as simple seems to be that hard to create in Blender …

Comment: @UnknownUser, please see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! Your fade affects the entire plane and if I wan't to address individual particles with the fade how would I go about that? Where could I plug my particle info (age/lifetime) node into? A simple add node doesn't seem to do the trick for me

Comment: Don't add, multiply ... alpha is a range 0 -> 1.0.  So if you add to another similar range you get 0 -> 2. TBH I don't know your exact use case, so unless you upload your file into the question using [our upoad facility](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) I can't really see what you are doing.  I just have an exploding monkey to test with.

Comment: For future reference, even a picture showing what you arw trying to do is helpful.  Remember that we are just other peeps on the interweb trying to interpret your question.

Comment: N.B particle node only works in cycles!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101949/discussion-between-unknown-user-and-moog).