# How to change the size of the particles over distance traveled

Tags: texturing, particles

I'm using a verticle blend texture to change the size of the particles the more they go up, to mimic a stylised blocky fire. It works, but the starting size of the particles change over time as well. So it looks like the "fire" is getting bigger and bigger over time. While I want it to be a constant starting size, and getting smaller the more it goes up.

Comment: maybe this answer will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114300/how-to-affect-particle-size-over-time/114310

Comment: I followed those steps, and I'm still getting the same issue

Comment: it should not, maybe share your file (just the emitter with its object)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/mSoJ3wzD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the method explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114300/how-to-affect-particle-size-over-time/114310). In the file you share the problem is probably that your gradient is vertical when it should be horizontal:

[image]

Comment: Yes! this worked, Thank you!